# Blockchain size on hard drive?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain-size

What is the current blockchain size in gigabytes and is there a service that regularly reports this statistic?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The current blockchain size is around 78 GB as of July, 2021.

On Windows platforms, you can check the size of the blockchain by checking the size of `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb\`.

On Linux/UNIX platforms, you can check the size of the blockchain in the terminal by executing `du -sh ~/.bitmonero/lmdb/`.

The Wolfram Warptangent v0.10.0 release bundled in some rather significant database optimizations started by the late developer warptangent (continued and finished by hyc), which shrunk the blockchain down to around 7 GB from 17 GB back in summer 2016.

The Monero blockchain grew fairly quickly in 2017 due to rapid adoption. An optimization known as "Bulletproofs" which significantly reduced the size of all subsequent transactions (~80% reduction) was activated on October 18th, 2018 with the v8 hard fork.

To check the current size of the blockchain (as well as look up historic growth of the blockchain), see https://moneroblocks.info/stats/blockchain-growth

Answer (score 5):

The blockchain database size is currently 21 GB.

Historical evolution is tracked at http://moneroblocks.info/stats/blockchain-growth. This site claims a smaller size, so it might be tracking the "raw" size, rather than the on disk database size (as the database duplicates some data in order to allow faster lookups).

Answer (score 1):

As of July 21st, 2017

**% cd ~**

**% du -k .bitmonero**

`3386256 .bitmonero/export
575384  .bitmonero/fake/lmdb
575384  .bitmonero/fake
21587512    .bitmonero/lmdb
25551504    .bitmonero`

Comment: so its 21GB... how do you store it? is your main system linux or mac?

Comment: The .bitmonero directory is located in my user account directory.

Answer (score 1):

Monthly Blockchain Growth:

https://moneroblocks.info/stats/blockchain-growth

Started April 2014. As of December 2017 it shows as 26 GB.

Answer (score 0):

There are two resources that report the blockhain size and growth over time.

http://moneroblocks.info/stats/blockchain-growth

[image: MoneroBlocks.info blockchain growth screenshot]

https://stoffu.github.io/diff-chart/monero-bc-size.html

[image: Stoffu blockchain size chart]

The second website loads a lot of information in the browser, so use a desktop browser only and be patient.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already run it you can simply do a ls on the lmdb directory. However, you probably want to know how much disk space it will take before you run the daemon monerod. So you want to do the equivalent of an ls on the currently running blockchains. As of today you can do the following:

```
:!x=$(curl -sd '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"get_info"}' http://node.moneroworld.com:18089/json_rpc | grep 'database_size' |  sed -r 's/.*: ([0-9]*)\,.*/\1/g'); y=$((x/1024/1024/1024)); echo -e "\tCurrent uncompressed Monero block chain is: "$y"GB"

Current uncompressed Monero block chain is: 140GB
```

If this ages out and you need a script that pulls from the latest let me know.