# Do you have to download the entire monero blockchain when using the core wallet? And how big is it?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, blockchain-size

As of July 2017, how big is the monero blockchain download and do you have to download the entire thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blockchain size: [Blockchain size on hard drive?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1789/blockchain-size-on-hard-drive)

By default - yes. Although, you can use remote nodes to sync the wallet:

[What is a remote node?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3656/what-is-a-remote-node)

[How much information is passed from the daemon to simplewallet when scanning for a wallet's transactions?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/how-much-information-is-passed-from-the-daemon-to-simplewallet-when-scanning-for)

There's a way without having to download the blockchain but it comes with a trade-off: you need to give your viewkey to some service and then it does the scanning for you.

[How does mymonero web wallet work?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/474/how-does-mymonero-web-wallet-work)

Centralization of users around such services comes with some risk:

[How can Monero defend against a "majority of view keys" attack?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3797/how-can-monero-defend-against-a-majority-of-view-keys-attack)

That's why the plan is to bake-in the backend to the official release, and enable anyone to run his own back-end (like, you let your PC be synced, and hook your mobile to it).